# Finding confidence intervals and coefficient for specific variable in the model

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, coefficients

I want to extract coefficients and confidence intervals at the same time for one of the variables from the regression model. I have to combine two separate codes, but I don't know how to combine them, and I want to save the result in a csv file.

the regression loop code

```
respvars <- names(QBB_clean[1653:2592]) 
predvars <- c("bmi","Age", "sex","lpa2c", "smoking", "CholesterolTotal")
results <- list()
for (v in respvars) { 
  form <- reformulate(predvars, response = v)
  results[[v]] <- lm(form, data = QBB_clean)
}
```

The separate codes I have

```
t(sapply(results, function(m) coef(summary(m))["bmi",]))

t(sapply(results, function(m) confint(m)["bmi",]))
```

Comment: This is a bad idea and a sure way to lead you to many false conclusions.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you for your input, but could you please tell me what you believe would be a better option? and I least I would like to know how to extract coefficients for BMI only and but it in a table and then save it in csv file.

Comment: That depends on what your goal is, this is a question better suited for cross validated stack. You would need to explain what your research question is, with context and details about your data.

Comment: @user2974951 Now I want to understand how BMI affect metabolites and I need confidence interval to draw forest plot.

Comment: It seems you're going to calculate 939 (metabolites) times 6 (predictors) = 5,634 coefficients. At a significance threshold of alpha = .05 that's five percent = about 280 coefficients significant "by luck" (the characteristic of your albeit random sample, not in the general population). Only that you don't know which.

Comment: OP is asking about how to achieve something specific by programming so I think this question is appropriate here.  It is very common in metabolomics to extract and combine regression results like this and to deal with false positives later by collectively adjusting the p-values for the comparisons you are interested in.

Comment: The `broom` package is likely to be of use here.  `broom::tidy()` with `conf.int=TRUE` will return tables of coefficients like `coef(summary())` but with confidence intervals included.  Using `emmeans` is another alternative.